# All labels with same height, on each row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap, is there an elegant way to make all the labels of a form to be of the same height, in each row, so that the inputs are bottom aligned with each other?

Please take a look at this [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/4wwav7fs/1/).

What I wanted is that the height of the 2nd label "*Same height as left*" to be the same height as the label on left. Alternatively, if the input on the right was bottom-aligned with the other input, that would also work.

Answer (score 4):

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4wwav7fs/3/)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="total_contribution_months">A very large and long label for an input</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="age">Same height as left</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input id="total_contribution_months" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <input id="age" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.
But is there any drawback in putting labels in one row and their corresponding controls in other row?

Comment: Oh, that breaks any responsiveness, because now one label follows the other :/

Comment: I think there are no drawbacks, cause label and input are linked to eachother with for and id attributes.

Explain your meaning of responsiveness, seems evrthg is ok :)

Comment: Well, the most direct drawback is that the controls don't fit on the same visual row, a label appears after another label.

Answer (score 1):

We usually would not sacrifice responsiveness by putting all labels into one row.

Solution: add an arbitrary height for your label and then push all label text to the bottom.

```
label {
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    display: table-cell;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Plese note `vertical-align` is effective only when `display: table-cell;`.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blaise_liu/4wwav7fs/9/)