# Bootstrap equal height form labels with responsive stacking

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

My question is very similar to this question:
[All labels with same height, on each row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33205080/811277)

Basically, just like the prior question, I have several form elements (label/input pairs) within several columns. My labels get translated and sometimes they take up 1 line and other times they take up 3. In the end I want these labels to be the same height so that the input fields are all on the same horizontal line.

One of the answers in the question suggests splitting the labels into their own row and the inputs into their own row. The problem is that when viewing at mobile screen sizes these items will stack and will look like:

```
label1
label2
label3
input1
input2
input3
```

This answer suggests and arbitrary height: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36409948/811277

However, I don't think it'll work if my labels ever take up more lines of height.

The only other thing I can think of is to utilize JavaScript to calculate the max height and then apply that height. However, I was hoping there was some sort of CSS/FlexBox/Bootstrap solution that I'm not seeing before I head in that direction.

**Edit:**

I am also looking have these elements stack when they at mobile sizes. For example:

```
label1
input1

label2
input2
```

Comment: Show the specific code.

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle from the original question:
https://jsfiddle.net/4wwav7fs/1/

I'm in the exact same situation with the exception that it must work for responsive/mobile sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**+ mobile**

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
 @import url('https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
 body {
    margin: 10px;
}


.row.flex {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
.row.flex .col-xs-6 {
    width: 100%;
}
label {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.row.flex {
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="total_contribution_months">A very large and long label for an input A very large and long label for an input</label>
            <input id="total_contribution_months" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <label class="control-label" for="age">Same height as left</label>
            <input id="age" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer looks pretty good. Though, I was hoping that at mobile sizes the form element groups would stack on top of each other. I should have called that out in the original question.

Comment: @Scott Dietrich See full page, resize window.